# which one is the main category of product

Tags: product, category, category-products, magento2.2.6

I need to take the main category . i try the following code

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($itemid);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
print_r($cats) // It returns  more than 1 category id
foreach ($cats as $category_id) 
{                   
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    echo "<br/>categoryid". $category_id;
    $collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($category_id);
    echo "</br> Category Name ". $collection->getName();            
    echo "<br/> Parent category name" . $collection->getParentCategory()->getName();                            

}
```

I have a doubt which one is the main category of the product ... I am not have much knowledge in ecommerce. I am struggle which one i need to choose.

Comment: what do you mean by main category?
there is no option of main category select in product

Comment: @Jigs , i want to know which one the exact category of that product. I got more than one category . for the single product

Comment: @JigsParmar , i ask about level of category how to get the category level . Top most and inner category . I need inner category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to get category level.

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($itemid);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
$level = 1;
foreach ($cats as $category_id) 
{                   
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    echo "<br/>categoryid". $category_id;
    $collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($category_id);
    echo "</br> Category Name ". $collection->getName();            
    echo "<br/> Parent category name" . $collection->getParentCategory()->getName();
    echo "<br/> Category level" . $collection->getLevel();
    $categoryName = $collection->getName();
    if($collection->getLevel() > $level) {
        $level = $collection->getLevel();
        $categoryName = $collection->getName();
    }                             

}
echo $categoryName; exit; // this will be the inner category name
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: welcome @SammuSundar Happy Coding :)